# Linq - Linq expression different context error

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 tables

```
- ERPEntry
- ERPEntryType
- ERPApp
```

I am trying to get data from these 3 tables using the below query but i got the error :

> specified linq expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts

```
var erpEntryInfo = (from s in ERPDB.ERPEntrys
                    JOIN t in ERPDB.ERPEntryTypes
                    on s.EntryTypeID equals t.EntryTypeID
                    join a in APPDB.ERPApps
                    on s.AppId equals a.AppId
                    where s.UserIDAdded == '250176'
                    select new ERPInfo
                    {
                       EntryId = s.EntryID,
                       EntryType = t.EntryTypeName,
                       ERPApp = a.ApplicationName,
                       DateAdded = s.DateAdded
                    }).OrderByDescending(d => d.DateAdded).Take(10).ToList();
```

I searched based on the errror and tried to split the above query into 2 as below.

```
var res = (from s in ERPDB.ERPEntrys
         join t in ERPDB.ERPEntryTypes
         on s.EntryTypeID equals t.EntryTypeID
         where s.UserIDAdded == '250176'
         select new {s.EntryTypeID, s.DateAdded, t.EntryTypeName, s.AppID }).OrderByDescending(d => d.DateAdded).Take(10).ToArray();

var y = (from a in APPDB.ERPApps
         join b in res on a.AppId equals //??//
         select new ERPInfo
         {
          EntryId = b.EntryID,
          EntryType = b.EntryTypeName,
          ERPApp = a.ApplicationName,
          DateAdded = b.DateAdded
         }).ToList();
```

I am having an issue in the above query to access AppId which i got into the result res..i commented with //??// in the above code

can i get any help on this.

Comment: Are they (`ERPEntry, ERPEntryType, ERPApp`) all in same context (`ERPDB`)?,

Comment: If `ERPDB` is a context then it's not clear where this comes from. Anyway, first, try to use navigation properties instead of joins. Then you'll always be in the same context for sure.

Comment: sorry, ERPApps is in another context APPDB.. apoligies for typo error.,, i have edited by post

Comment: are you really tried ``b.AppID``?

Comment: If `ERPApps` isn't a long list, get them all and join in memory.

Comment: @Sajid my bad, i was trying to access AppID with x.AppID and i was not able to.. now i tried with b.AppID but when i tried running it i got this error - 'Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context'

Comment: @GertArnold ERPApps almost has 10,000 records in it, will it be feasible ?

Comment: Just try and see. If you only fetch AppID and ApplicationName then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Juan, i think the error is here ``EntryId = b.EntryID``, yo have two choice : 1- change it to ``EntryTypeID`` in ``y`` request or 2- change it to ``s.EntryID`` in ``res`` request. if it's work fine, i can build an answer to the question. because in the current code, You use ``EntryID`` in ``y`` request, but you select ``EntryTypeID`` in ``res`` request.